# Why is Perl DBI escaping values retrieved from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl, escaping, dbi, dbd

I have a value in MySQL that contains an apostrophe (`’`) and an ellipsis (`...`):

```
$ /bin/echo "select alias from url_alias where source = 'node/12024'" | \
  mysql --skip-column-names -D cat36ia_d7prod
```

**Output:**

```
forum/technical-discussion/nagging-questions-i’ve-been-too-embarrassed-ask…
```

When I retrieve the value with Perl `DBI` and `DBD::mysql`, the value has been changed:

```
$ perl -MDBI -MDBD::mysql -e
      '$dbh=DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:database=my_db",nick );
       $v=$dbh->selectrow_array(qq|select alias from url_alias where source = "'node/12024'"|);
       print "$v\n";'
```

**Output:**

```
forum/technical-discussion/nagging-questions-i?ve-been-too-embarrassed-ask?
```

Why is Perl doing this? Can I override it?

Comment: This is not an "escaping" issue; it's an issue with characterset translation. By default, Perl uses ASCII for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR; and yes, you can override that behavior. Also, your database connection may be specifying a characterset that doesn't support the code points. And yes, that can be overridden as well. A couple of articles you should have under your belt: [**The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: And the other article: [**What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text**](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Tell Perl how to encode the output.

   ```
   use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   ```
2. Get the data from the database as text by using

   ```
   DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=my_db", $user, $pass, {
      mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about encoding the output.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to tell DBI to use UTF8 when talking to the database.

```
$dbh=DBI->connect(
   'DBI:mysql:database=my_db', $user, $pass,
   { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that DBI param but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Why is Perl doing this? Can I override it?

It's not being escaped. That's a symptom of a characterset translation issue. The question mark character is a default character used when a code point doesn't map to any other character in the target characterset.

---

The short answer, as to why Perl is doing this may be: by default, Perl outputs to STDOUT using ascii characterset. Since ASCII only supports code points up to U+00EF, all other code points (for example, characters 128 thru 255) get translated to a question mark character.

The short answer as to how to override this behavior may be: specify that STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR use utf8 encoding rather than ascii by including a line like this in your perl program:

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

---

Another potential issue is the setting of the MySQL session `character_set_client` variable; the database connection may be using a `latin1` characterset, but the database/server/column characterset may be `utf8`, so a characterset translation may also be occurring there.

And it's possible to specify the characterset to be used in the database connection, to avoid an unwanted characterset translation.

---

As a starting point of understanding charactersets, here's two references you should have under your belt:

[**The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

[**What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text**](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)